# Run Xcode Server bots in simulator

Tags: ios, xcode7, xcode7.1, xcode-bots, xcode-server

I have created some Bots to build, analyze and run unit tests, but I have not been able to make it work in a simulator. All integrations always finish with 12 errors, one for every simulated device.

> Assertion: Test target **MyAppTests** encountered an error (The operation couldn’t be completed. (OSStatus error -1712.) If you believe this error represents a bug, please attach the log file at /Library/Developer/XcodeServer/Integrations/Integration-7d62a04eb43957f1d3098c8ffb64cc13/Session-2016-06-22_20:00:39-svEh7I.log)

This same error repeats itself 12 times. I believe it has something to do with the simulators because the tests only pass on the real devices.

[image]

Is there some trick that needs to be done for the simulators to work? The bot configuration for devices is to test with **All iOS Devices and Simulatos**.

Thanks in advance.